# SQL Oracle 21c XE, ORA-01017 Invalid User / Password

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-xe, oracle21c

[SQL Plus command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8Rl1.png)

Hello everyone,

New to programming and I'm taking a PL SQL course. I am supposed to enter the commands listed above, but I can't seem to connect to the database. It says I invalid user/pw everytime.
The teacher was using 18c, and I'm on 21c so I'm not sure if that matters. How can I fix this?

Thanks

I tried reinstalling and giving only one command at a time. Google couldn't bring anything up for 21c either.

Comment: Please post your commands as formatted text in the question, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

`grant` was never executed. You should have terminated the command with a semi-colon (as you did in `alter session`) or a slash.

This is what you did:

```
SQL> select * From dual
  2
SQL>
```

See? No result. With a terminator:

```
SQL> select * from dual;
                       ^
D                      |
-                  terminator
X

SQL>
```

---

Apart from that, see whether you have to provide database name with `connect`. Depending on its name, it could've been something like

```
connect scott/tiger@pdb1
```

Comment: I thought I tried that, but I guess not. New to this stuff, thank you.